# How do I print (cout) a nested structures variables

Tags: c++, dynamic, nested, structure

I need to figure out how to make "*struct* snack" that is "inside *struct* candybar" be able to be outputted and I can't figure it out. I've looked all over the internet and in my textbook and can't find anything that works. 
Also how could I make the array *array* become a dynamic *array* using *new?* Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main(){

struct candybar 
{
    char name[15];
    float weight;
    int calories;
    struct Snack
    {
        const char * name2 = "Mocha Munch";
        double weight2 = 200;
        int calories2 = 2;
    };
};
candybar array[3] = 
{
    {"Kit-kat", 2.3, 250},
    {"Hershey", 2.2, 252},
    {"Snicker", 2.5, 255},
};

cout << array[0].name << " " << array[0].weight << " " <<  array[0].calories << endl;
cout << array[1].name << " " << array[1].weight << " " << array[1].calories << endl;
cout << array[2].name << " " << array[2].weight << " " << array[2].calories << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/ and define `Snack` above `candybar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structs inside structs are not defined like this. You want to move the definition to the outside of the struct

```
struct Snack
{
    const char * name2 = "Mocha Munch";
    double weight2 = 200;
    int calories2 = 2;
};

struct candybar 
{
    char name[15];
    float weight;
    int calories;
    Snack snack;
};
```

Now you have a member `snack` of type `Snack` in your `candybar` and can access it, for example `array[0].snack.name2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct candybar
{
    char name[15];
    float weight;
    int calories;
    struct Snack
    {
        const char* name;
        double weight2;
        int calories2;
    };
    Snack snack;

};
candybar array[3] =
{
    {"Kit-kat", 2.3, 250, {"a", 100, 100}},
    {"Hershey", 2.2, 252,{"b", 200, 200}},
    {"Snicker", 2.5, 255,{"c", 300, 300}}
};
```